# If with input, i can't find the mistake

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's wrong with this code? I can enter(input) anything I want and it prints "Nice".

```
print ("Hi and welcome to our online shop.\n\nWhich fruit would you like to buy? Apple, Banana or Strawberry?")

x = input()

if x is "Apple" or "apple":
    print ("Nice.")

elif x is "Banana" or "banana":
    print ("Great.")

elif x is "Strawberry" or "strawberry":
    print ("Cool.")

else:
    print ("Please enter a avaliable product")
```

It's my first code, so it might be a small mistake.
Thx for your answers.

Comment: `"Apple" or "apple"` is always `True`

Comment: Or to be more precise `"apple"` is considered to be `True` and anything `or True` is `True`.